# what is the correct way to implement structured data logging?

Tags: json, logging, serilog

I am just starting to learn about structured data in writing events to a log file.  There is one conceptual problem that I fail to grasp/understand and I am looking for answers to.

The information logged for one event is generally very different from information logged for another event.   Assume one event logs user information such as the users first and last name, a second event logs information about parameters passed to a function, a third event logs information about a NULL variable exception, and so on.  The key point here is that the information logged is extremely different.

In the past, I generally logged all this information as text in the same log file and then spent time manually reviewing all of it.  I am using the Serilog framework to test writing JSON formatted structured data to a log file.  It works...but what a mess!   The JSON data structure emitted from one logged event to another is so different that a visual review is no longer possible.  And it would be very difficult for a computer program to parse and analyze this mess.

Instead of logging all events to the same log file, am I supposed to log each type of structured data event to it's own log file so that each log file uses only a single JSON data structure?  Obviously I am missing key points about how to properly implement/use structure data in logging events.  Can someone explain to me what I have missed?

Comment: I'd recommend to go play with https://getseq.net - that'll convey what you can achieve. The _structured_ in structured logging is that the individual messages have structure. You can lift stuff out of that by building queries and alerts etc.

Comment: I just quickly scanned the Seq documentation and it seems this is the missing link that I was not aware of.   Thanks for the reference.  It will be a big help, especially since I had no idea of what to do next.